# Where/How do I include the navigation bar in a yii view

Tags: php, yii

I am new to PHP frameworks and yii and I am trying to understand how views/layouts work. This is how I currently understand how to layout a page template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="page_wrp">

        <?php include 'includes/top_right_nav.php' ?>

        <div id="content_wrp"> 

            <div id="content">

            </div>

        </div><!--#content_wrp-->

        <?php include 'includes/main_nav.php' ?>

    </div><!--#page_wrp-->

</body>
```

I understand that basic yii way is more like this:

```
<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo CHtml::encode($this->pageTitle); ?></title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container" id="page">

<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name); ?></div>
</div><!-- header -->

<div id="mainmenu">
            <!--
                DON'T WANT TO USE ZII.WIDGETS FOR MENU
                WANT TO KNOW BEST WAY TO INCLUDE MY ONW NAVIAGTION MENU-
            ->
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array('...')); ?>
</div><!-- mainmenu -->

<?php echo $content; ?>

<div id="footer"></div><!-- footer -->
```

What I don't understand is what is the best practice/analogous way to include my own navigation bar in the context of yii/MVC. Can I still use includes as above or do I have to use zii.widgets? If it's ok to use includes where do I put the files?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use Yii widgets however it's recommended to use them, they are quite flexible.

Make a view file for your menu markup in the layouts folder, something like _myMenu.php

_menu.php

```
<ul>    
    <li>menu item 1</li>
    <li>menu item 2</li>
</ul>
```

then in your layout use `renderPartial()` to render your _menu.php partial view inside your layout.

main.php

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <?php $this->renderPartial("//layouts/_menu"); ?>
</div>
```

This is a really simple solution, if you want to make the menu more dynamic you can add a method to your controller to handle this.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work OK. I just need to figure out how and why . I have so much to learn! Thanks again.

Comment: in your view `$this` always refers to your controller class so $this->renderPartial() is a method of CController - when "//layouts/_menu" is passed to it the controller goes and looks for _menu.php in layout folder then inserts it into the view. You can also pass data to your partial views as well - this article could help clear things up http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/249/understanding-the-view-rendering-flow/

Comment: Now use `<?= $this->render('_menu'); ?>`